# Sorting array of objects by two criterias?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects that i want to sort by two keys. The objects lets say are of type **Student** and the properties that i'm intrested in for my sort are **grade** and **name**.

```
Student
{
    double grade;
    string name;
    ...
}
```

How can i sort the objects first by grade and then by name? so for example if i have the list:
Tom 9.9
Andrew 9.8
Chriestie 10
Mat 9.8
Allison 10
Ada 9.8

After the sort i should have:
Allison 10
Christie 10
Tom 9.9
Ada 9.8
Andrew 9.8
Mat 9.8

And not 
Christie 10
Allison 10
Tom 9.9
Andrew 9.8
Ada 9.8
Mat 9.8

any pointer is really helpful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm pretty flakey on my objective-c knowledge but there's some good pointers [here](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/02/tutorial-tips-sorting-filtering-filter-nsmutablearray-and-sorting-nsmutablearray-by-ascending-or-objects-items-or-specified-key-or-key-value-or-by-nsnumber/) and there's always the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingDescriptors:). Here's my crack at it...

```
NSSortDescriptor *gradeSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"grade" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *nameSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

[personList sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:gradeSorter, nameSorter, nil]];
```

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it in my opinion. Sorting using sort descriptors allows you to achieve any level of hierarchical sorting. i.e., all objects are sorted according to the first sort descriptor, any remaining duplicates are sorted according to the second third descriptor, and so on. If you want, see http://github.com/LucasTizma/spot_trot_helpers#nsarray+stadditions for my category on `NSArray` (`NSArray+STAdditions`) that helps consolidate the syntax for using sort descriptors.

Answer (score 3):

You basically need to implement your own comparator and use one of `NSArray` sort methods (e.g. [`sortedArrayUsingSelector:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingSelector:))

```
-(NSComparisonResult)compare:(Student *)student {
  // sort by name
  int nameComp = [name compare:student.name];
  if (nameComp != NSOrderedSame) return nameComp;

  // reverse ordered as desired in the question
  if (grade > student.grade)
    return NSOrderedAscending;
  else if (grade == student.grade) // watchout here
    return NSOrderedSame;
  else
    return NSOrderedDescending;
}

NSArray *unsrtedArray = ...
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

_pScheduleArr : The name of array in my below code. This array contains the custom model object. I compare the array on behalf of date and alphabetical order. Date is also present in the array inside array(core data model).

_pScheduleArr = [[_pScheduleArr
      sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Meetings *obj1,
                                                     Meetings *obj2) {

```
    NSOrderedSet *personSetObj1 = obj1.timeSlots;
    Timeslot *tt1 = [[personSetObj1 array] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSOrderedSet *personSetObj2 = obj2.timeSlots;
    Timeslot *tt2 = [[personSetObj2 array] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDate *date11 = tt1.startTime;
    NSDate *date12 = tt2.startTime;

      NSComparisonResult comresult = [date11 compare:date12];
      if (comresult == NSOrderedSame) {
          comresult = [obj1.title compare:obj2.title];
      }
      return comresult;

  }] mutableCopy];
```